# Database level using php

Tags: php, database

I have two kinds of users in database (teacher / student)

How can i show some functions of my website ( button / review section  )for teacher only and vice versa ?

i want to know the concept and any thing to help me

i got an error telling me that Undefined variable user while i am using the same query in another page

```
<div class="container">
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button    <?php if($user[0]['type']=="student")?> type="button" id="mah" 
class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" 
>Add Course</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Add Course</h4>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
 <form action="/action_page.php">
  Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
  <br>
  Course Name<br>
  <input type="text" name="Add_course" value="">
  <br>
   Course Link<br>
  <input type="text" name="Course_link" value="...">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form> 
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
   dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
   </div>

   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Query the database to get the user level, then use an `if` statement to display different HTML depending on this.

Comment: Put your code in the question, with proper formatting, not a comment.

Comment: Indent code with 4 spaces

Comment: Show more of the script so we can see how you're setting `$user`.

Comment: i want that attached code to work with type student only

Comment: Where is the code that sets `$user`? It's complaining that this variable isn't set.

Comment: i am using codeginter where i can find the defined user  ?!

Comment: I have no idea, I don't use codeigniter. How do you do it in the other page?

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest have a different section for teacher and the other for student . Using logic based on the names "teacher/student" the have different teacher adds marks , register student. while student view his enrollment .

Since the code is incomplete do a `var_dump()` on your array $user your can see if the value exist